# Python Selenium Ajax jquery: How to know when jquery (bootstrap) is done updating the page so I can take a screenshoot

Tags: python, jquery, selenium, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to take a screenshot after the page is done loading and all the jquery is done. The page loads in IE, Edge and FireFox but all three browsers will occasionally run jquery a little to slow and I get a trasitional image of jquery working.

```py
start_time = time.perf_counter()

ClickActionElement = Utility_Element_Verify.ID_Element(self,
            ElementID = ElementID,
            ElementDescription = ElementDescription)

webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(ClickActionElement).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(ClickActionElement).click(ClickActionElement).perform()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID , WaitElementID)))

end_time = time.perf_counter()
time_elapsed = (end_time - start_time)
self.TestEventLog += "<br />LoadTime: Admin page and the Specific Ajax was completed before: " + str(time_elapsed) + " seconds"
```

What do I do to make sure jquery is all done here before I take a screen shot?

```
Utility_Capture_Screen.CaptureScreen(self)  # sometimes it's to fast
```

The image is saved but sometimes the jquery has not completed. How can I detect the jquery is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if jQuery is completed using `jQuery.active` status. Inside your `WebDriverWait` use `lambda` to check jQuery status.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return jQuery.active == 0'))
```